# Mysql FROM_UNIXTIME

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 PHP variables formatted for DATETIME, but the column is in UNIX timestamp. How do I correctly do a BETWEEN on them?

`$date_from` and `$date_to` are in DATETIME format.
`dateline` is stored as a UNIX timestamp.

The following isn't working:

```
if($date_from != "" && $date_to != "") {
    $result_pag_num = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM messages WHERE (folder = '$folder' AND username = '$username' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline) BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to')");
} else {
    $result_pag_num = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM messages WHERE (folder = '$folder' AND username = '$username')");
}
```

*Edit:* all answers were good. I accepted the person who replied the fasted. The error was my own fault.

Comment: What you have should work. Just be sure the MySQL timezone is set correctly before doing that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to change the query to

```
... AND dateline BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$date_from') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$date_to')
```

This way MySQL can use an index on the dateline field. You version forced it to convert every dateline field to a datetime value before doing the comparison, making index usage impossible.

Otherwise, the query looks fine. Are you sure the `$date_from` and `$date_to` are properly formatted, and there's records that fit all the clauses in the query?

Comment: This didn't work for me.  $date_from is `2011-03-11 00:00:00` and $date_to is `2011-03-11 23:59:59`. An exmaple dateline is `1299526727`

Comment: Well, those two dates come out to `1299823200` and `1299909599`. Your `1299526727` is smaller than both, so it's not "between".

Comment: The use of the FROM_UNIXTIME() function on a TIMESTAMP column does not disable the use of an index in MySQL 5.1, with the InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 1):

If your `dateline` columns in the database is stored as a timestamp, **you should convert the PHP variables to timestamp**, and not convert the `dateline` column to datetimes.

**Why ?**

In order to avoid applying the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function to that column : if you do use that function like you posted, MySQL will have to scan the whole table for each request, applying that function to all lines...

... which means you'll loose the advantage of any index you might have on `dateline` -- and have your MySQL server do more work.

So, rewrite your query the other way arround : convert the `DateTime`s PHP variables to UNIX timestamps *(the datatype you have in your database)*, using [`DateTime::format`][1] with a `U` format :

```
$ts_from = $date_from->format('U');
$ts_to = $date_to->format('U');

$result_pag_num = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
                    FROM messages WHERE (
                        folder = '$folder' 
                        AND username = '$username' 
                        AND dateline BETWEEN $ts_from AND $ts_to
                    )");
```

As a sidenote : maybe you're doing that earlier in your code, but don't forget to properly escape your data -- especially strings, using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`][2].

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the FROM_UNIXTIME function. Since the `dateline` column is datatype TIMESTAMP, MySQL will do the conversion for you:

```
AND dateline BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2011-03-11 17:00'
```

To really investigate the issue, we need to know the actual contents of the $date_from and $date_to variables, and the actual statement being passed to MySQL.

Also, timezone settings may influence how datetime values are interpreted and compared.

If you are passing unixtime style integers, then you should omit the single quotes (to avoid any possibility that MySQL is doing a string comparison)

```
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline) BETWEEN 1299801600 AND 1298998800
```